# Как сгененировать GUID код внутри textBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите, есть ли способ сгенерировать GUID код, с фигурными скобками?

Например: `{475bfe7f-e9a0-4524-82db-8329e896bb8e}`

Как в сервисе Online GUID Generator

Желательно, чтобы его можно было генерировать в `textBox` по нажатию на `pictureBox`

Comment: а добавить скобки руками никак?

Comment: Можно и без них, все равно GUID нужно будет вставлять в путь реестра.

Comment: то есть вопрос в том, как в принципе сгенерить его? дак вроде [`Guid.NewGuid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx) из `System`?

Comment: Да, только, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку он появлялся в `textBox`, сам я не соображу, лишь по шаблонам смогу определиться...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот честное слово, первый раз создал в VS проект WinForms.
На форму кинул кнопку `button1` и `textbox`.
двойными кликом по кнопке и получил обработчик события клика в коде. Добавил код генерации `GUID` с помощью [`System.Guid.NewGuid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx). Для добавления фигурных скобок использовал `String.Format`, сами фигурные скобки необходимо экранировать парными.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //использования обычного форматирования
    //textBox1.Text = String.Format("{{{0}}}", Guid.NewGuid());

    //использование параметров метода toString()
    textBox1.Text = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("B");

    //комбинация двух верхних вариантов 
    //textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:B}", Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Comment: Вместо `{{{0}}}` красивее будет написать `{0:B}`. См. [Guid.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, конечно, что-то я не дочитал доки :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил к коду, спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за упрощение с фигурными скобками `{0:B}`

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

по нажатию на button

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "{" + (Guid.NewGuid()).ToString() + "}";
    }
```

идентично и по нажатию на pictureBox

```
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "{" + (Guid.NewGuid()).ToString() + "}";
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за примеры, без осуждения.